# Shorthand way to initialise a 2D/3D array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, initialization

I was wondering if there is a shorthand way to initialise a 2D or 3D array in C similar to the following syntax:

```
int array[1024] = {[0 ... 1023] = 5};
```

Comment: You apparently left out the "1D" in your title, which is what your posted code actually is. Not sure what the "D" has to do with your question, come to think of it.

Comment: You example is a gcc extension. What do you mean by *in C*?

Comment: That's a [GCC extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html), it's not standard C.

Comment: @WhozCraig I was asking if there was a way to init multidimensional arrays using the '[first ... last] = value' syntax - the code I posted was just an example of using this syntax with a standard array. Thanks all for correcting my mistake though.

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate but answers the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21528288/c-structure-array-initializing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The initialization you use isn't standard C, it's a [GCC extension (Designated Initializers)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html#Designated-Inits).

To initialize a 3d array, use:

```
int array[10][10][10] = {[0 ... 9] [0 ... 9] [0 ... 9] = 42};
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/zscOCy).