# How to intalize the structure with same value(not 0) in C

Tags: c

I tried memset to assign all the structure members to 0 as given below, but it didn't work.

```
struct sample
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
    int e; 
    int f;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct sample s1;

    memset(&s1, 1, sizeof(s1));
    printf("%d",s1.e);

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: In which way did it not work?

Comment: Please explain your understanding of the parameters to memset you use and compare it to e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset

Comment: Btw you can initialize like `struct sample s1 = { 0  };`. `memset()` is not needed here.

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21528288

Answer (score 0):

`memset` can be used to initialize an object to all bits zero, which is appropriate to set all `int` member values to `0`.

For non zero initial values, there are several alternatives:

```
    struct sample s1 = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }; // using an initializer
```

or

```
    struct sample s1;
    s1.a = s1.b = s1.c = s1.d = s1.e = s1.f = 1;  // initializing the members explicitly
```

or

```
    static struct sample default_sample = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
    struct sample s1 = default_sample; // copying values from another structure.
```

Answer (score -1):

> I tried memset to assign all the structure members to 0
>
> ```
>  memset(&s1, 1, sizeof(s1));
> ```

This will definitely not zero the struct members.

And this will:

```
memset(&s1, 0, sizeof(s1));
```

If you want to set them to the another value you need to answer one question : *How portable do you want it to be?*

The portable way:

```
 struct sample s1 = { 1,1,1,1,1,1};  // initialisation

s1.a = 1;
s1.b = 1;
s1.b = 1;
s1.d = 1;
s1.e = 1;
s1.f = 1;
```

Non portable way (assuming the same type  and no padding between members):

```
#define NMEMBERS 6
int *ptr = (void *)&s1;
for(int index = 0; index < NMEMBERS; index++, ptr++)
{
    *ptr = 1;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
memset(&s1, 1, sizeof(s1));
```

The above code doesn’t set structure members to 1 as `memset` works `byte` by `byte`. Hence each `byte` of your `structure` will have value `1`

If you want to initialize the structure members other than `0`. You can do as below.

```
struct sample s1 = { 1,1,1,1,1,1};
```

or Initialize each members separately after declaration.

Comment: Understood..Thank you for all the answers